# Erro ao criar uma animação entre rotas usando o Angular 5

Tags: angular

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que usa a mais atual estrutura do Angular (v5). Já tinha feito a implementação do `BrowserAnimationsModule` em versões anteriores e não tive problemas mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo criar essa animação. Meu código está a seguir:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

// app module element'ss
import { AppRouterModule } from './app.router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { RegistrarComponent } from './registrar';
import { EntrarComponent } from './entrar';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        RegistrarComponent,
        EntrarComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRouterModule,
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**app.transitions.ts**

```js
import {
    trigger, style, transition, animate, query, stagger, keyframes
} from '@angular/animations';

export const fadeIn = trigger('fadeIn', [
    transition('* <=> *', [
        query(':enter', [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            animate('1s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ], { optional: true }),
    ]),
]);
```

**entrar.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { fadeIn } from '@app/app.transitions';

@Component({
    selector: 'entrar',
    styleUrls: ['./entrar.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './entrar.component.html',
    animations: [fadeIn],
    host: { '[@fadeIn]': '' }
})
export class EntrarComponent { }
```

**registrar.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { fadeIn } from '@app/app.transitions';

@Component({
    selector: 'registrar',
    styleUrls: ['./registrar.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './registrar.component.html',
    animations: [fadeIn],
    host: { '[@fadeIn]': '' }
})
export class RegistrarComponent { }
```

Teoricamente, o código acima deveria fazer com que quando houvesse qualquer transição entre as 2 rotas, a rota de saída e de entrada deveria sumir e aparecer com uma animação de 1 segundo mas não ocorre.

Uma ajudinha ai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa da uma olhada neste [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-supercharge-your-router-transitions-using-new-animation-features-v4-3-3eb341ede6c8)

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { fadeIn } from '@app/app.transitions';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    template: '<main [@fadeIn]="getState(o)">
                 <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
               </main>',
    animations: [fadeIn]
})
export class AppComponent {
  getState(outlet) {
    return this.routingService.getDirectionAnimation(outlet);
  }
 }
```